# DBRD dual primary Heartbeat resource management

Tags: linux, drbd, heartbeat, ocfs2, heartbeat1

I have the following setup:

- Two servers with DRBD running dual primary with OCFS2
- Heartbeat with two virtual ips, one for each server
- Round robin DNS to load balance NFS across the two vIPs

Shutting down Server1 for a period of time, cause Server2 to take over the vIP for failover. However, when Server1 returns - it takes over the designated vIP as soon as heartbeat gets connection again - even though the DRBD is running sync (and thus not up to date)

How can I configure heartbeat to perform failback as soon as Server1 again is in sync with Server2 ? (And not before)

Answer (score 0):

> However, when Server1 returns - it takes over the designated vIP as
>   soon as heartbeat gets connection again - even though the DRBD is
>   running sync (and thus not up to date)

To disable auto failback, you can set the default resource stickiness to INFINITY by running:

```
crm_attribute --attr-name default-resource-stickiness --attr-value INFINITY
```

http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLE-HA/SLE-ha-guide_sd_draft/cha.ha.configuration.basics.html#sec.ha.configuration.basics.constraints

Comment: Not what I asked though - I'm looking for a way to automate the process, compared to manual management. Heartbeat has a regular option in ha.cf for `auto_failback off` as well.